# JSON file size is much higher than expected(Storing Local Language)

Tags: java, json, database, sqlite, utf

Wrote a tool to convert data in an excel to JSON.
I only have 100 records, total of 1000 cells of data.

**JSON got created is whopping 265MB.**

1. Data Sample: കേന്ദ്ര തിരഞ്ഞെടുപ്പ് കമ്മീഷൻ എല്ലാ
   തിരഞ്ഞെടുപ്പുകൾക്കും ഉപയോഗിക്കുന്നത് മൈസൂർ പെയിന്റ്സ് ആന്റ് വാർണ
2. Code is normal:Object.toJsonString(), and writes using File Writer.
3. JSON file out: I can observe lots of \u200D and \u200C
4. Excel file: Size  is merely 40KB

Please help, I am expecting a file size of < **1 MB**

Part of the JSON output is

െ അമേരിക്കന്\u200D പ്രസിഡന്റ്? ","options":["എബ്രഹാംലിങ്കണ്\u200D","ജോര്\u200Dജ് വാഷിംഗ്ടണ്\u200D","തോമസ് ജഫേഴ്\u200Cസണ്\u200D","കെന്നഡി"]}]}]}]}

I would like to remove \u200D and

Comment: 1) `\uXXXX` are Unicode escapes, and should not be considered something illegal. 2) Does `.toJsonString()` create a string? If so, it's waaay better to write to the output stream directly. 3) Not sure what JSON writer you're using exactly, but Gson does not emit Unicode escapes. 4) Why do you expect it to be less than 1MB? Do you strip document related metadata? 4-1) Your characters take at least 2 bytes whilst Unicode escapes take 6 -- the most you can expect here is ~88 MB if not using Unicode escapes. 4-2) Do you consider ZIP streams?

Comment: 3)JSON writer is json-simple-1.1.1.jar 4) I just want to save the strings. How do i remove document related meta data?

Comment: 4) It was a suggestion or an assumption since I have no clue if you really have metadata there like Excel spreadsheet/sheet styles, data definitions, formulas, etc-etc-etc. Did you check it? I mean are you really sure that you're extracting calculated cell values only? What is the general structure of your result JSON after all?